# Online check-in for Tui flight to Reus Airport (Costa Dorada)

Tags: air-travel, check-in, tui

in desperation I've joined this site as am travelling to Spain on Tuesday (17th May) and am so confused.

I'm travelling with my mum in law and my 8 year old daughter (her first flight) and have been seeing horror stories about huge queues at airports so am trying to make sure everything is squared up as much as possible before we go.

Our local travel agents say they can't print boarding passes as the planes keep changing due to high demand.

It's that long since I've flown I can't even remember what happened last time I went, I think I just checked in online.

Anyway, I have checked in online for the outgoing journey, and downloaded the boarding passes to an app on my phone.  But nowhere in my online account does it give the option to do the same for the return journey.  What do we need to do to get boarding passes for the return journey?  Has anyone travelled with Tui recently and had this issue?

thanks so much for reading

Comment: What is your departing airport ?

Comment: Check-in may not open until X hours before your return journey starts.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.tui.co.uk/destinations/faq/when-does-online-check-in-open?catId=261&subcatId=319&docId=1155

> If you're flying with TUI, online check-in opens 14 days before your flight takes off. You'll need to check in for your outbound and return flights separately. Online check-in for your outbound flight is available right up until three hours before take-off and, for your return flight, closes six hours before take-off.

So if your return flight is more than 14 days away, online check in will not yet be available. You will be able to check in when your flight is less than 14 days away. This may be once you are already in Spain.

Note that if you are referring to the problems at UK airports, these largley relate to shortages of security staff and while obviously checking in online gives one less thing to worry about, it won't help you with queues for airport security. If the airport you are travelling from is known to be having difficulties, all you can do is arrive earlier than you might normally do.

Comment: Something like that for the long lines on Schiphol, Amsterdam, and while the worst seems past, coming early does not hurt.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  We're flying from Bristol airport.  Our return flight is less than 14 days away.  Thanks again :-)

Comment: If it's less than 14 days away and you can't check in online, I think you'll have to ask TUI directly.